# How to create anchor tag in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, anchor, laravel-5.1

I need help as I am trying to create anchor tag in Laravel 5.1

I used this line & this works

```
{!! Html::link('/dashboard','Dashboard') !!}
```

But I have code like this

```
<a href="#" class="logo">
  <span class="logo-mini"><b>cpy</b></span>
  <span class="logo-lg"><b>Company</b></span>
</a>
```

I want to fit above code into Laravel 5.1 link format , but i am unable to get it .
Someone help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use URL or route to anchor element.

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('dashboard')}}" class="logo">
  <span class="logo-mini"><b>cpy</b></span>
  <span class="logo-lg"><b>Company</b></span>
</a>
```

This  points to /dashboard. If you wish to suffix a parameter for example base-path/dashboard/user-name

then,

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('dashboard', $username)}}" class="logo">
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>cpy</b></span>
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Company</b></span>
 </a>
```

When using URL, makes sure the path is set in routes.php